# Why treadmill motor speed controllers are not interchangeable?

Tags: motor, dc, pid-controller

Why treadmill motor speed controllers are not interchangeable? I just wonder why, if two different treadmills have different upper control consoles and different controllers why we can not switch controller despite they have the same connection cable with Vcc, Gnd, Tx, and Rx?

Comment: I bet some are.

Comment: Make a new consortium of treadmill manufacturers and produce only equal treadmills.

Comment: The communication protocols are probably different.

Comment: That's like saying why can't we switch an automobile engine from one  car to another.  After all all cars have the same controls.

Comment: Because upper consoles aren't the same. Just because they have tx and rx doesn't mean they speak the same language. Humans all have mouths and ears. It doesn't mean we all understand each other without "reprogramming" (learning a new language).

Answer (score 3):

This is an economic question, not an engineering question.

Excluding a government mandate, standardization only occurs when it is a benefit to the manufacturer. This most likely has not happened, and maybe never will.

From a manufacturers point of view, standardization is often bad. For example, another company can make replacement modules cheaper and you lose business.

How standardization can be successful: companies A, B, C & D get together and decide to standardize. Standard parts are now produced in greater quantities and costs go down. You take business away from companies E, F & G.